# JavaScript Overlay effecting images behind it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

**BACKGROUND:** I have a page of images that are responsive so on mobile they show in one column. Well the first time a user visits my page I have a JavaScript pop up that ask if they want to be on a mailing list.

**MY PROBLEM:** In mobile when the pop-up overlays the images they all stretch to a width of 960px; but before the pop-up all of the images load normal size for mobile. So the images load normal for a second until the pop-up loads. Finally when the pop-up is closed the images do not resize until you change the orientation of the browser or resize it (if tsting on desktop).

**Question:** How can I test what is going on with the images that are being stretched? Can I add a listener in JS to update the console every time their width changes? Can I some how tell who or what is updating their widths?

Comment: downvoted. at 1500 points you should know by now that you need to include the relevant code.

Comment: I tried to sneak in the question real quick before I had to log off. I now have sometime to edit my question with additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story very short the issue I was experiencing was because the pop-up modal was adding a class the the HTML tag of the page. That class "no-scroll" was setting position:fixed to the HTML tag. For some reason when this happened and the modal popped up on the stage all of the viewable images in the background would stretch as if they were being viewed on Desktop not mobile. Once that attribute was removed from the no-scroll class

This was a very random and poorly asked questions that should have been researched more before being asked.